# jQuery - toggle selected items

Tags: jquery, html-lists, toggle, nextuntil

I have a problem with jQuery task. I have to toggle 'ol' context after click on header:

My html:

```
<h3>Task</h3>
    <ul>...</ul>
    <ol>...</ol>

<h3>Second Task</h3>
    ...
```

My jQuery script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('h3').click(function() {
        $(this).nextUntil('h3').toggle(); 
    })
})
```

My code toggle all context between h3 headers, but I need toogle just 'ol'. 
Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: `togggle`? or `toggle`?

Comment: toggle of course, my mistake sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.last()` to toggle just the last element in the collection (which is the `ol` in this case).

**Update:** In case you should have something after your `<ol>`, it's better to use `.filter('ol')` to make sure that you only target the desired list.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('h3').click(function() {
        $(this).nextUntil('h3').filter('ol').toggle(); 
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Task</h3>
    <ul><li>list1-1</li><li>list1-2</li></ul>
    <ol><li>list2-1</li><li>list2-2</li></ol>

<h3>Second Task</h3>
```